# How to use a calculated column to calculate another column in codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter, subquery

i hope you can help me with this simple question.
i try to use this nested query in codeigniter.

```
Select
  ColumnA,
  ColumnB,
  calccolumn1,
  calccolumn1 / ColumnC as calccolumn2
From (
  Select
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB,
    ColumnC,
    ColumnA + ColumnB As calccolumn1
from testtable
);
```

how to convert this to codeigniter?
i know the inner SELECT should look a bit like this:

```
        $this->db->select('ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC,ColumnA + ColumnB As calccolumn1'); 
        $this->db->from('testtable');
        $subquery = $this->db->get();
        ...
```

but then how do i have to proceed?

Comment: You can use (which is encouraged) `$this->db->query('YOUR COMPLEX QUERY HERE')`.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to more complicated queries I usually just do this:

```
$variable = 'x';

$query = $this->db->query(" 
        SELECT... 
        FROM... 
        WHERE some_column = '$variable'
    ");

return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you fast reply! 
The query is working fine now! but i cant seem to find how to add the WHERE clause with my variable ($data) from the method which i wanted to add now.
normally i use

$this->db->where('Username', $data);

but since the where clause is now in the query, i didnt find a way yet to add it inside the query.

Comment: I've updated my answer which should address this (You should use comments to request clarification instead of posting an answer)